# iPhone 4s mic is worse than iPhone 4 mic

Tags: iphone, ios, microphone, audioqueueservices

I'm using *Audio Queue Framework* with sample rate 44100 Hz to record data from the microphone on iPhone.

Then I test **frequency response** for iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s.
**iPhone 4s** mic is blind on frequencies higher than 20 kHz unlike iPhone 4.

It seems like the microphone is better on previous model.
Is it hardware limitation? Is it software limitation? Or some misconfiguration (enabled noise compession or something else)?

Comment: The spec for both mics is only up to 20 kHz, so it would seem the iPhone 4S hardware anti-aliasing filter might actually be *better* than the one on the ip4.

Comment: When you get that close to the Nyquist frequency, it's just noise anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can hear frequencies that high - for most people, the threshold is somewhere around 15kHz.

So the 4s cuts out unnecessary frequencies - potentially making it better than the iPhone 4.